# Duplicity Error accessing possibly locked file

Tags: 14.04, backup, home-directory, duplicity

I am experimenting with Duplicity. I am trying to backup my home directory to a local directory:

duplicity --no-encryption /home/user file://home/user/backuptmp

When I run this, I notice a few errors complaining about locked files:

Error accessing possibly locked file /home/user/.cache/dconf

Error accessing possibly locked file /home/user/.gvfs

Error accessing possibly locked file /home/user/.viminfo

(sometimes I see an error regarding .dbus)

I'm wondering, how critical are these errors? Will the backups be corrupted and/or not finish if these errors are not resolved? I know I can create an exclude file to exclude these files, but I just want to know how big of a deal these errors are. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it simply means duplicity could not access these files. hence they will not end up in your backup.

make sure the files are readable (check permissions or runtime locks) if you want them backed up
 or
as you wrote, simply exclude them.

..ede/duply.net