# duplicity 0.7.06 crashes

Tags: command-line, backup

My daily incremental duplicity job crashes:

```
duplicity-

inc.20160210T210502Z.to.20160211T210503Z.vol4.difftar.gpg]
Last full backup date: Sun Oct  2 20:04:33 2016
Error accessing possibly locked file /run/user/1000/gvfs
/home/tpollak/bin/backup_duplicity_incr_exclude_media: line 65:  3826 Killed                  duplicity -v4 --log-file /home/tpollak/backupIncrLog --volsize 1000 --exclude /boot --exclude /cdrom --exclude /dev --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /tmp --exclude /home/tpollak/.gvfs --exclude /home/tpollak/Downloads --exclude /home/tpollak/Trash --exclude /media / ftp://Tommy@192.168.1.100/Tommy/for_duplicity
```

Error in call or known bug?

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/629089/duplicity-error-accessing-possibly-locked-file ?